# How does a recorder boost a signal at line-in?

Tags: recorder, line-level

This might seem like a dumb question, but don't let that fool you. It is a dumb question.

Say I connect my mics to my MixPre-D, and then connect my MixPre-D to my Sony PCM M10 recorder via line-in.

Using the recorder, I can attenuate or boost the signal. Apparently unity gain is at 4 on the PCM M10, so that's what I leave it at.

But . . . what's boosting the signal if I turn up the gain on line-in? If it's not the recorder's on-board preamp doing the work, what is?

Cheers
Ian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often (but not always) "gain" on a line-in is actually attenuation. "Line-In" can refer to a number of different signal levels, ranging from -10dbV to +6 dbu (this part you may already know). A "line-in" jack can be set to take say -10dbV, at 0 attenuation, and then attenuate the signal accordingly as the signal get's hotter. However "gain" is more consistent terminology with how we audio folks work, so it's often expressed in this fashion. So at -10dbV for example is set as a gain of "10" (using a 1-10 scale) which is NO attenuation, +4dbu at "4" and say +6dbu at a gain of "0" which is actually MAX attenuation.

In some cases however, the "line-in" is set at a nominal level (let's say +4dbu) and then an amplifier circuit will provide gain for lower level signals. The difference in this amplifier circuit is a question of gain- hence the term "pre-amp" - something that processes the signal "pre" or before another amplifier. The amplifier at line level wants to see a considerably louder signal then at mic level and provides less gain, making it a much simpler circuit.

Some decent Wikipedia (i.e referenced) articles can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_amplifier)